# Misleading compiler error message: size_t is not a member of std?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, size-t

I have the following header file containing a template class:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

namespace lgl
{
    namespace maths
    {
        template<class T, std::size_t SIZE>
        class Vector
        {
        public:
            Vector();
            Vector(T defaultValue);
            Vector(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other);
            Vector<T, SIZE>& operator=(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other);
            ~Vector();

            //accessors
            const std::size_t size() const;
            const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const;
            T& operator[](std::size_t i);

            //vector operations
            Vector<T, SIZE> operator+(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other) const;
            Vector<T, SIZE> operator-(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other) const;
            Vector<T, SIZE> operator*(const T& scalar) const ;
            Vector<T, SIZE> operator/(const T& scalar) const ;
            T operator*(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other) const;

            void operator+=(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other);
            void operator-=(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other);
            void operator*=(const T& scalar);
            void operator/=(const T& scalar);

            bool operator==(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other) const;
            bool operator!=(const Vector<T, SIZE>& other) const;

        private:
            T m_elements[SIZE];

        };

        template<class T, std::size_t SIZE>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector<T, SIZE>& vec);

        template<class T>
        Vector<T, 3> cross(const Vector<T, 3>& a, const Vector<T, 3>& b);

        #include "Vector.tpp"

        //typedefs
        typedef Vector<float, 2> vec2f;
        typedef Vector<float, 3> vec3f;
        typedef Vector<float, 4> vec4f;
        typedef Vector<double, 2> vec2d;
        typedef Vector<double, 3> vec3d;
        typedef Vector<double, 4> vec4d;
        typedef Vector<int, 2> vec2i;
        typedef Vector<int, 3> vec3i;
        typedef Vector<int, 4> vec4i;

        //factories
        vec2f getVec2f(float x, float y);
        vec3f getVec3f(float x, float y, float z);
        vec4f getVec4f(float x, float y, float z, float h);
    }
}

#endif
```

The .tpp file has all the implementations of the methods of the Vector template class. I also have a Vector.cpp file, which defines the factory functions, like this:

```
#include "Vector.h"

namespace lgl
{
    namespace maths
    {
        //factories
        vec2f getVec2f(float x, float y)
        {
            vec2f result;
            result[0] = x;
            result[1] = y;
            return result;
        }

        vec3f getVec3f(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            vec3f result;
            result[0] = x;
            result[1] = y;
            result[2] = z;
            return result;
        }

        vec4f getVec4f(float x, float y, float z, float h)
        {
            vec4f result;
            result[0] = x;
            result[1] = y;
            result[2] = z;
            result[3] = h;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the errors: size_t is not a member of std, and ostream is not a member of std. 
If I delete everything in the .cpp file and don't use the factories, everything's fine. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you include the proper headers, such as `<iostream>`?

Comment: Post the full code. `#include`'s are crutial here. Btw, `ostream` is in `<ostream>` and `size_t` is in `<cstddef>`.

Comment: As a side note, you can probably take look at std::array in C++11, since you are pretty much reinventing it...

Comment: I edited the question, full code is posted. It's just for practice, I'm a student.

Comment: Ok so I included iostream in Vector.h and it works now. However, if I don't include it, and I delete Vector.cpp's contents, it works. If I restore Vector.cpp but don't include iostream in the header, I get the errors. Why does this happen?

Comment: One problem is you are including `Vector.hpp` from within a namespace. All definitions and declarations in `Vector.hpp` and the ones in files included by `Vector.hpp` will be in `lgl::maths`. Since you didn't include `Vector.hpp` it's hard to tell how much of an impact this will have.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy std::array doesn't implement scalar multiplication or cross products.
That said, while the standard library does not have a "mathematical vector" class, about 2000 libraries already have an implementation of such a vector

Comment: @KABoissonneault There's always [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I guess no matter how much you think you know the standard library, there's always going to be some useful feature that you  don't know about.

Answer (score 5):

Write

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <iosfwd>
#include <cstddef>

namespace lgl
{
//...
```